# Observer update() causing a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, singleton, observer-pattern

I'm trying to use the Observer pattern to notify the observer(s) of a `BroadcastReceiver` that a new message has been received. When the `update()` method in the activity is called, the fields in the activity should be updated so that the message can be displayed on the screen. However, I keep getting a `NullPointerException` at that point.

Here is an excerpt from the related log:

```
04-15 13:03:21.252  31107-31107/com.example.sam.yak E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sam.yak, PID: 31107
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.sam.yak.Receive: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2698)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1434)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.sam.yak.SendActivity.update(SendActivity.java:94)
        at com.example.sam.yak.Receive.notifyObservers(Receive.java:82)
        at com.example.sam.yak.Receive.onReceive(Receive.java:53)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2687) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:153) at       android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1434) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The relevant code for `SendActivity` (the observer) is as follows:

```
public class SendActivity extends Activity implements Observer {

private static SendActivity send;
String message;
String sender;
Receive receive;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send);
    sender = "";
    message = "";
    receive = Receive.getInstance();
}

public static synchronized SendActivity getInstance() {
    if (send == null)
        send = new SendActivity();
    return send;
}


@Override
public void update() {
    message = receive.getMessage();
    sender = receive.getSenderNumber();
    retrieve();
}
```

also, relevant code for `Receive` (the observable):

```
public class Receive extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static Receive receive;
String sender = "";
String message = "";
List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();
SendActivity send = SendActivity.getInstance();

public Receive() {}

public static synchronized Receive getInstance() {
    if (receive == null)
        receive = new Receive();
    return receive;
}

/**
 *
 * @param context
 * @param intent
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
    //newMsg = false;
    addObserver(send);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(!(bundle == null)) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            //newMsg = true;
            setSender(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress());
            setMessage(msgs[i].getMessageBody());
            Toast.makeText(context,msgs[i].getMessageBody(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            notifyObservers();
        }
    }
}

public void setSender(String s) {
    sender = s;
}

public void setMessage(String s) {
    message = s;
}

public String getSenderNumber() {
    return sender;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void addObserver(Observer o) {
    if((o != null) && (!observers.contains(o))){
        observers.add(o);
    }
}

public void notifyObservers() {
    for(Observer l : observers) {
        l.update();
    }
}
}
```

Any feedback & recommendations greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Which strings? The sender and message fields are already initalised.

Comment: i think `receive` has not been initialized. if receive will be null then `receive.getMessage();` will throw NullPointerException

Comment: I cut out all of the unnecessary code. Line 94 is: message = receive.getMessage(); in SendActivity

Comment: Receive is a singleton so I initialised is as receive = Receive.getInstance() in SendActivity

Comment: line no 94 in sendActivity?

Comment: Yes. Line 94 in SendActivity is message = receive.getMessage();

Comment: try to initialize and declare at same point. `Receive receive =Receive.getInstance();`

Comment: No, that prevents the SendActivity from opening. The following is displayed in the logcat:

Comment: at com.example.sam.yak.SendActivity.<init>(SendActivity.java:22)
            at com.example.sam.yak.SendActivity.getInstance(SendActivity.java:66)
            at com.example.sam.yak.Receive.<init>(Receive.java:23)
            at com.example.sam.yak.Receive.getInstance(Receive.java:30)
            at com.example.sam.yak.SendActivity.<init>(SendActivity.java:43)
            at com.example.sam.yak.SendActivity.getInstance(SendActivity.java:66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure but I think your usage of singletons is problematic. Suppose `SendActivity` is created first. In its `onCreate` method `Receive.getInstance()` is called, which in turn calls `SendActivity.getInstance()` but the `SendActivity` instance is not ready yet. I don't think your Receive class is ever properly initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Activity life-cycle is managed by the Android operating system.

I wouldn't suggest making your activities and broadcast receivers singleton, because you don't know when they are created, whether they are null or not.

My solution to your problem would be to use some sort of event-bus, instead of the Observer pattern.

greenrobot's EventBus is a great one:https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus and it isn't that hard to learn, either

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to initializing the "*send*" variable explicitly with the null value.

private static SendActivity send;

Change it to,

private static SendActivity send = null;